# How to add unused disk space in HDD to /home

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, disk

This is the condition of my current partition.

[image: Disk Properties]

I have 8 GB of swap space. The extended partition has 492 GB among which only 100 GB is usable, which is /dev/sda5. Then a 1 GB boot partition, which is /dev/sda6. And then there is a 391 GB file system partition /dev/sda7 which is almost empty. Is it possible for me to add this space to me /home directory?

Additional Information:
When I checked my disk properties it was shown that this empty partition is mounted as /Foo. (i.e., inside the root folder). But this space is not shown when we check the properties of computer (root). But there is a folder inside root as /Foo and when I check the properties of that folder It shows It has more than 360 GB free space. Since the owner is root,I am unable to copy anything to this folder as a normal user.

My file system type is ext4.

Please feel free to ask if any additional information required.

**EDIT:**

This is my GParted screenshot when opened with Gksudo. [image]

Answer (score 2):

- Ensure your computer is plugged into the power
- Make a [System Backup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) (You've just been promoted to User type 4)
- Boot from an Ubuntu Live-DVD or a [gparted Live-CD](http://gparted.org/livecd.php)
- Start gparted and you will see something like this:

[image]

- Click the right side of `/dev/sda7` and drag it to the left (="shrink partition")
- Move the partitions around, so there is enough space to:
- Click the right side of `/dev/sda5` and drag it to the right (="grow partition")
- Click the green **☑**
- Go to sleep as this is going to take all night!

Comment: I have a problem now. It doesn't actually getting shrinked. I know It would shrink if it were unused space. Bu actually the space is part of this Ubuntu partition and user has no access to it. :(

Comment: In that screen, just edit the "New Size" number to have it be what you want it to be: if I understood you correctly about 10% of its size, so type `32798` (you've probably double-clicked or right-clicked instead of click-and-drag.)  Could you also delete all of your comments as this is starting to look like a chat room!  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you join / remove a partition, be sure to remove it from /etc/fstab also: else the OS keeps looking for it.